# Sort a list based on another list in Dart

Tags: arrays, list, dart, sorting, arraylist

I need to sort `unsortedList` based on the sorting of `sortedList`.

Example:

```dart
List<String> sortedList = ["x", "a", "c", "d", "w"];

// [unsortedList] items need to be also in [sortedList] and in the
// same range (eg. between 0 and 2 position)
List<String> unsortedList = ["a", "x", "c"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the elements of `sortedList` which also appear in `unsortedList`, in their original order.

That's not about sorting.

No sorting is needed:

```dart
var result = sortedList.where({...unsortedList}.contains).toList();
```

(You can use `unsortedList.contains` directly, instead of creating a set, and it's probably even faster for small `unsortedList`s.)

Or, if your requirement is correct, and the *n* elements of `unsortedList` are the first *n* elements of `sortedList` in a different order, then maybe just `var result = sortedList.sublist(0, unsortedList.length);`.

If you actually care about getting the *element* from `unsortedList`, not the equal element from `sortedList` (which may matter if the elements are equal, but not identical), you can do:

```dart
var result = sortedList.map({...unsortedList}.lookup).whereNotNull().toList();
```

where `whereNotNull` is from `package:collection`.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following code on [DartPad](https://www.dartpad.dev/)

```dart
void main() async {
  List<String> sortedList = ["x", "a", "c", "d", "w"];

  // [unsortedList] items need to be also in [sortedList] and in the
  // same range (eg. between 0 and 2 position)
  List<String> unsortedList = ["a", "x", "c"];

  final outcome = List<String>.generate(unsortedList.length,
      (index) => unsortedList.firstWhere((item) => item == sortedList[index]));

  print(outcome);
}
```

[image]